# How to pass a struct by reference and change its value

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference, stack

Hello everyone I have this problem with my C code.
I'm implementing a stack and whenever I do pop it changes the stack in the function pop, but not the original stack .
please help.

here is my code

```
char pop(Node* top)
{
    char result ; 

    if (size == 0) // The stack is empty.
    {
        return '\0' ;
    }

    else //The stack contains at least one element .
    {
        result = top->opp ;
        top = top->next ;
    }

    size-- ;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: by looking at the code, i'd suggest you make few edits 1. you dont delete `top` passed to you at start, so it's a memory leak, 2. since it's stack you don't need `size`, you can simply check `if(top != NULL)` means stack isn't empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more code but I will try:

I guess you use this function like this:

```
char pop(Node* top)
{
    char result ; 

    if (size == 0) // The stack is empty.
    {
        return '\0' ;
    }

    else //The stack contains at least one element .
    {
        result = top->opp ;
        top = top->next ;
    }

    size-- ;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
   // this is the top of the stack
   Node    *stack; // let's say there already are some elements in this stack
   pop(stack);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that you want to change the pointer value, then `stack` will point to the top of the stack. In order to do that, you have to use a pointer to a pointer, like this:

```
char pop(Node** top)
{
    char result ; 
    Node *ptr;

    ptr = *top;
    if (size == 0) // The stack is empty.
    {
        return '\0' ;
    }

    else //The stack contains at least one element .
    {
        result = (*top)->opp ;
        (*top) = (*top)->next ;
        // You should free the pointer, like user2320537 said in his answer.
        free(ptr);
    }

    size-- ;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
   // this is the top of the stack
   Node    *stack; // let's say there already are some elements in this stack
   pop(&stack); // You give the pointer address
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try char pop(Node** top) and operate on (*top)

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the current position of top also... use free as

```
Node *ptr;

ptr = top;

if (size == 0) // The stack is empty.
    {
        return '\0' ;
    }

    else //The stack contains at least one element .
    {
        result = top->opp ;
        top = top->next ;
    }

    free(ptr);
```

=================================================================

call it as

```
int main(){
 Node front = NULL:

 // place your code of PUSH here.

 pop(&front); // will call the function **pop**

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you change the value of a variable you pass a pointer ( its address) to a function 
eg

```
void increment(int *p) {
      p += 1;
}
```

similarly to change the value of a POINTER you need to pass a pointer to the pointer to the function

```
char pop(Node **top) {
       char t;
       Node  *p;
    if( size == 0 ) {
        return '\0';
    } else {
        p = *top;
        t = p->op;
        (*top) = (*top)-> next;
        free(p);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please send reference of top pointer to pop function like as "char pop(Node **top) { }" and add change your else block "top[0] = top[0]->next;" instead of "top = top->next ;".